# Control with Overrides on Inherited Form is Called Twice in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, overriding

I am working on some code that inherits a form and overrides some controls. In the example below, the overrides sub is called twice (the message box appears twice).

```
' (ProjectBase.vbproj)
Public Class FormBaseMain
  Protected Overridable Sub ButtonDoStuff_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonDoStuff.Click
    ' Do nothing for now
  End Sub
End Class


' (TestApp.vbproj)
Public Class FormNewMain
  Inherits ProjectBase.FormBaseMain

  Private Sub FormNewMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RemoveHandler ButtonDoStuff.Click, AddressOf MyBase.ButtonDoStuff_Click ' Doesn't help
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub ButtonDoStuff_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonDoStuff.Click
    MsgBox("test")
  End Sub

End Class
```

The parent sub does not appear to be called since a breakpoint on the sub is not hit.

Does anyone know why this happens or how to fix it?
Is there a better way to override controls?

Comment: It does appear both subs are called. This is from Debug Output:
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'TestApp.FormNewMain.get_ButtonDoStuff'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'ProjectBase.FormBaseMain.get_ButtonDoStuff'

Comment: The fact that you have deleted your own answer suggests that you have found the other answer useful. If that answer has indeed solved your problem, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. That rewards the person who posted the answer with reputation points but, more importantly, it shows everyone that your problem has been solved without their having to open the question. Those with accepted answers are specifically indicated in question lists.

Answer (score 4):

How many times do you see `Handles ButtonDoStuff.Click` in your code? I see it twice, so you're handling the event twice. Of course `RemoveHandler` doesn't help, because that can only do something if you used `AddHandler` in the first place.

Don't override the event handler at all. Declare it exactly like you would any other event handler. Have it call anther method to do the work and override that in the derived class. That way, there's only one `Handles` clause. In code, that should look like this:

```vb
Public Class FormBaseMain

  Private Sub ButtonDoStuff_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonDoStuff.Click
    DoStuff()
  End Sub

  Protected Overridable Sub DoStuff()
    ' Do nothing for now
  End Sub

End Class
```

and this:

```vb
Public Class FormNewMain
  Inherits ProjectBase.FormBaseMain

  Protected Overrides Sub DoStuff()
    MsgBox("test")
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: One small note: I think the usual naming convention for the overridable routine called from the event handler is to prefix it with `On` e.g. `OnDoStuff`.

Comment: @Craig, nope. That is the convention for naming a method that raises an event. The `Click` event is raised by the `OnClick` method. You would name a method `OnDoStuff` if and only if it raised an event named `DoStuff`. Such a method would be declared `Protected Overridable` but that's not the reason for the name.